# Delete duplicate Chinese characters in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['重庆市重庆花园','北京市市教育中心']})
```

How I can delete the duplicated characters of rows in column 'a', and make it as

```
['重庆市花园','北京市教育中心']
```

instead of

```
['重庆市重庆花园','北京市市教育中心']
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## `OrderedDict`

You can drop duplicates without losing order using an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict    
df['a'] = [''.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(v)) for v in df['a']]
df
         a
0    重庆市花园
1  北京市教育中心
```

On python-3.6+, you can just use a standard dictionary—

```
df['a'] = [''.join(dict.fromkeys(v)) for v in df['a']]
```

---

## `str.extractall` + `groupby` + `drop_duplicates`

This is the ugly alternative—

```
(df.a.str.extractall('(.)')[0]
   .groupby(level=0)
   .apply(pd.Series.drop_duplicates)
   .groupby(level=0)
   .agg(''.join)
)

0      重庆市花园
1    北京市教育中心
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using

```
df.a.apply(list).apply(lambda x : ''.join(sorted(set(x), key=x.index)))
Out[169]: 
0      重庆市花园
1    北京市教育中心
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: `sorted` + `x.index` is O(N^2 logN), on top of a apply x2 is a recipe for suboptimal performance.

Comment: HOWEVER, this is quite clever, so I like it ;-)

Comment: @Wen thank you, but what if the characters could be `'重庆市重庆重花园'`, but i want to make it as `'重庆市重花园'`, is it possible do this kind of deleting without manual check?